# What is the difference between two cases of "impact", with and without "on/upon"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I see Oxford Learner's Dictionary offers two examples for entry of "Impact". The meaning is "to have an effect on somebody/something". One example is with proposition of "on/upon" and the other is without. It seems that "on/upon" can be omitted. Is there any difference?

- Impact on/upon somebody/something:
  *Her father's death impacted greatly on her childhood years.*
- Impact somebody/something:
  *Environmental factors that may negatively impact children's development.*
  *The company's performance was impacted by the high value of the pound.*

Comment: Purely aesthetically, I'd prefer "impact on", although the transitive form is useful in the passive. But [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impacted+him%2C+impacted+on+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for "impacted him" vs "impacted on him" shows the version without "on" is much more common (this may reflect the large number of technical publications in NGram data); same with "it". No difference in meaning though.

Comment: There are various examples where [verbₜᵣₐₙₛᵢₜᵢᵥₑ] + [direct object] and [verbᵢₙₜᵣₐₙₛᵢₜᵢᵥₑ] + [prepositional phrase] are synonymous. brush / brush against //// appeal / appeal against //// jeer / jeer at ////  fight / fight with or against ////  arguably pass / pass by  (some would say this is a 'phrasal verb', but again there is synonymy).... This is one such example.

Comment: I prefer to use "impact" without "on" because of simplicity, if both ways have almost the same meaning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the examples provided, both "impact on/upon" and "impact" without a preposition are used to convey the idea of having an effect on someone or something. The inclusion or omission of the preposition "on/upon" does not significantly change the meaning of the sentence.

However, the usage of "impact on/upon" may sometimes imply a slightly more direct or specific relationship between the subject and the object being affected. On the other hand, using "impact" without a preposition might be perceived as a more general statement of influence or effect.

In practical terms, the choice between using "impact on/upon" and just "impact" may depend on stylistic preferences, the context of the sentence, or the desired emphasis. Both forms are widely used and understood in contemporary English.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I also think there is very slight difference between these two expressions. The preposition  may stress "towards somebody/something" , I think. Anyway, the difference is very minor. Some other words, that can be both intransitive or transitive and have different meanings, are more important. For instance, approve, with or without "of".